# Tell Node script to execute 2 commands

Tags: node.js

I start my app with `node server.js` command

And this works to run my tests:

```
  "scripts": {
    "test": "node node_modules/karma/bin/karma start test/karma.conf.js",
  }
```

Now now, when I run the test script, I want it to first execute `server.js` before starting the tests.

But this doesn't work:

```
  "scripts": {
    "test": "node server.js node node_modules/karma/bin/karma start test/karma.conf.js",
  }
```

How can I get my test script to do both?

Answer (score 0):

You forgot the semi-colon after the first command:

```
"scripts": {
    "test": "node server.js; node node_modules/karma/bin/karma start test/karma.conf.js"
}
```

Comment: After starting the app with server.js, it runs indefinitely. The tests never start.

Comment: One solution would be to start the server from within your test script;

`require('../server.js'); console.log('hello world');`